# Creating vertical lines given a non-numeric x-axis

Tags: line, stata

i have a bar chart in Stata with the code below. Now I want to create a vertical line between 2 bars.

```
graph bar (max) CAAR_Automotive CAAR_Motion_Picture CAAR_Business_Services CAAR_Chemicals CAAR_Communications CAAR_Hotels CAAR_Airline
```

Is it possible to do it?

Using the `xline()` option did not help me.

Comment: `xline()` is an option of `graph twoway`, not `graph bar`.  I can't (yet) think of a way to do this without switching to `twoway bar`.

Comment: I've left the mention of an x axis in the title -- but the point is that the horizontal axis is not considered to be an x axis at all (as it's categorical).